# HTML Forms and Posting Data

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm currently in the process of updating my family business' website with the assistance of a template. In essence what I am trying to do is as follows:

On my homepage (temporarily: http://alchemistifical.com/mw/index.html) I have 4 
    input fields and a button. These I wish to use to send a POST data request via HTML to
    my online booking page. 
    Located at: https://bookings.rms.com.au/rmsobookings/(S(oamzli45zh2yuwq1kcr0rmon))/default.aspx?clientid=6466&agentid=1&hideavail=1&hideroom=1

I have extracted what data is sent in a POST request with the assistance of HTTPHeaders and this is what I have:

```
sm=sm%7CbtnGo&txArrival=10-Nov-2014&txAdults=1&txDeparture=14-Nov-2014&txChildren=0
```

There is further useless text that is posted as part of this request as well, such as the information actually displayed on the page and what appears to be a bunch of repetitively encrypted text.

So in essence the data I wish to post is:

```
txArrival=(insert text date here)
txAdults=(insert number here)
txDeparture=(insert text date here)
txChildren=(insert number here)
```

Is this doable with HTML/Javascript and if so, can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm more familiar with Visual Basic and Java Wrapper's used for posting data then I am with this sort of stuff. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with very basic HTML. You won't need javascript until you want to make sure that the form is filled out completely before being submitted. Save that for a later step.

Take a look at the w3schools forms tutorial. It should cover everything you need:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

If you want to pass txArrival, you'll need an input named "txArrival". That's the "name" attribute, not the "id" attribute.

Comment: I had a look at this last night, the problem I encountered was that when I set it up, I couldn't work out how exactly to set the post correctly, nor could I get the data to go across when I set the button up.

Comment: I just added a note about how to name your inputs.

Comment: I and someone else have had a go at passing the inputs in, now we're getting hit with redirects that seem to block the input from ever occurring.

Answer (score 0):

What you've done right: set the "destination" in "action" and method to `post`. You now need to give your form fields the same name that the destination/action expects. Id can remain unchanged E.g:

```
<select name="txAdults" id="adults" class="dk"><!--Options--></select>
<select name="txChildren" id="children" class="dk"><!--Options--></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track regarding posting using HTML.
However, I'd suggest you take a look [here](http://www.rms.com.au/our-products/rms-online/developers/), as you'll need to understand what information and in what format to send to the rms booking system. Their [API documentation](http://kb.rms.com.au/Channel_Management/RMS_Online_API) will provide this detail.